# How to make a layout with colored boxes around sections

Tags: sectioning, color, margins, boxes

I am trying to reproduce the following layout with latex:

[image: Example page]

Is there any package or document class made for such a layout? The example is made in word using tables. But I think using tables in latex for this is not a good idea, because the syntax will be a bit to complicated. For example solution which just modifies the section command and adds the frame around the page would seems to be a better syntax.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}


\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm,hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pagestyle{empty}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\colorbox{blue}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textcolor{white}{\thesection\quad#1}}}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{}{0em}{\colorbox{blue}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}}

\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\begin{document}



\section*{Gefahren für Mensch und Umwelt}

Die aufgrund der Strombegrenzung (ca. \SI{20}{\micro A} ) nicht berührungsge-
fährliche Gleichspannung (bis zu \SI{200}{kV} ) kann für gefährdete Personen
(z. B. Personen mit Herzschrittmacher) lebensgefährlich sein.

\section*{Schutzmaßnahmen und Verhaltensregeln}

\begin{itemize}
\item Vor Inbetriebnahme Überprüfung auf ordnungsgemäßen Zustand.
\item Zur Beschaltung nur Hochspannungskabel verwenden.
\item Änderungen im Versuchsaufbau nur im abgeschalteten und entladenen
Zustand.
\item Spannungsführende Teile nicht berühren.
\item Gefährdete Personen (z. B. Personen mit Herzschrittmacher) dürfen sich
beim Betrieb nicht in der Nähe des Bandgenerators aufhalten.
\item Da nicht ausgeschlossen werden kann, dass Schüler gefährdete Personen
sind, dürfen sie mit Bandgeneratoren weder experimentieren noch an
Experimenten mitwirken.
\item Keine Kondensatoren (z. B. keine Leidener Flaschen) anschließen (Lebensgefahr aufgrund von berührungsgefährlichen Spannungen).
\end{itemize}

\section*{Verhalten bei Störungen und im Gefahrenfall}

\begin{itemize}
\item Bandgenerator abschalten und entladen.
\item  Schäden oder ungewöhnliches Verhalten des Bandgenerators den Vorgesetzten melden. Entsprechende Bandgeneratoren nicht in Betrieb nehmen
und einer weiteren Nutzung entziehen.
\end{itemize}

\section*{Verhalten bei Unfällen -- Erste Hilfe}

\begin{itemize}
\item Bandgenerator abschalten bzw. vom Netz trennen
  (z. B. Not-Aus betätigen) und entladen. Auf Selbstschutz achten.
\item Erste Hilfe leisten (z. B. Schockbekämpfung) bzw. Ersthelfer
  verständigen (Information z. B. an Sekretariat oder Hausmeister
  weiterleiten), Eintrag ins Verbandbuch.
\item Auch bei scheinbar folgenlosem Stromschlag Arzt aufsuchen.
\item Notruf: 112
\end{itemize}

\section*{Instandhaltung}

\begin{itemize}
\item Reparaturen nur von Fachleuten durchführen lassen.
\end{itemize}

5. Dezember 2015

\vspace*{1ex}
\hrule
\vspace*{1ex}
\centering
Datum, Unterschrift (Dr. S. Lübeck)
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

I am also not sure what's the best way to make the heading, so I left it out in my example code. Same for the columns in each section. Using minipage for every section doesn't seem to be very elegant.

Comment: `tcolorbox`, but I would not (ab)use the `\section` command for this!

Comment: Why not (ab)use the section command?

Comment: Well, I leave it to you then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How would you implement this using tcolorbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Christian offers a better solution, you can start with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
sharp corners,
boxrule=2mm,
notitle,
colback=white,
colframe=blue,
coltitle=white,
fonttitle=\bfseries]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\tcbsubtitle[before skip=\baselineskip,halign=center]%
{My subtitle}
Further text.
\tcbsubtitle[before skip=\baselineskip,halign=center]%
{Another section}
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.3\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: While 'Christian offers a better solution'? You already did it with `tcolorbox` ;-)